# How to access custom property in dataset object in Bar Chart in React ChartJS 2?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartist

I would like to know the "userId" custom property when I click on the element.

If I add a custom property to the dataset object, the custom property added doesn't show in the element retrieved in getElementAtEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Since you barely gave any specifications on where you tried accesing your custom property I went with that it was in the dataset itself, if this is the case you can acces it like this:

```
onClick: (evt, elements, chart) => {
    alert(chart.data.datasets[chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true)[0].datasetIndex].customProperty)
  }
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-bar-with-groups-and-patterns-forked-xeblf?file=/src/BarChart.js

Comment: I'm using react-chartjs-2 (2.10.0). In your code, you are using react-chartjs-3 (3.0.3). Could you answer in react-chartjs-2?